# Angular Routing Example

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm newbie in angular js I try to make the following routing example but it did't work.
The example in the following url http://plnkr.co/edit/dd8Nk9PDFotCQu4yrnDg?p=preview

```
// create the module and name it scotchApp
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'mainController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
});

scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

The is index page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <!-- define angular app -->
 <html ng-app="scotchApp">

 <head>
 <!-- SCROLLS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/
 font-awesome.css"  />

 <!-- SPELLS -->
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>

 <!-- define angular controller -->
 <body ng-controller="mainController">

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 </nav>

 <div id="main">

 <!-- angular templating -->
    <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
 <div ng-view></div>

 </div>

  <footer class="text-center">
  <p>View the tutorial on 
  <a href="http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/
  single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating">Scotch.io</a></p>


  <p>View a tutorial on <a href="http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/
       animating-angularjs-apps-ngview">Animating Your Angular Single Page App</a></p>
 </footer>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Can any one help me please?

Comment: So what doesn't work? Demo seems to be fine.

Comment: yes,but it doesn't work with me I copy the code from this demo.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not going to get you any help. What isn't working? What happens (or doesn't) to indicate it isn't working. What does the console say?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have copied the exact code from the given link there cannot be anything wrong in the code. is the path you have given in the html is correct?

is src="script.js" the actual place of your script.js?

Answer (score 1):

The above code works fine. If you still have any trouble with it, kindly share the error message. Also dont forget to open this application on client server architecture. You can also try any local server or a plugin from chrome browser.

Here is the link for another Angular UI routing example : [Angular UI Routing Example](https://github.com/TheAjinkya/Angular-UI-Router)